# Why Jersey doesn't honor the priorities in dynamically bind filters?

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

I am using the `DynamicFeature` in [Jersey](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/filters-and-interceptors.html#d0e10049) to dynamically bind a container request filter to some particular resource methods. In addition to the `DynamicFeature`, I also have regular filters that apply to all resource methods. However, I found the priorities/orders of these filters not working as expected. For example:

```
public class MyDynamicFeature implements DynamicFeature {

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceInfo resourceInfo, FeatureContext featureContext) {
        featureContext.register(MyDynamicFilter.class, 2);
    }
}

public class MyDynamicFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {
    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext containerRequestContext) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Hey! I am dynamic!");
    }
}

public class MyStaticFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {
    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext containerRequestContext) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Hey! I am static!");
    }
}
```

In the `ResourceConfig`, I register the `DynamicFeature` and filters with priorities:

```
register(MyDynamicFeature.class, 1);
register(MyStaticFilter.class, 3);
```

Ideally, if requests comes through the filters, I'd expect to see from the log:

```
Hey! I am dynamic!
Hey! I am static!
```

because the dynamic filter has a higher priority than the static one, but instead, I saw

```
Hey! I am static!
Hey! I am dynamic!
```

So it seems like dynamically bound filters always come at the end after the statically bound ones. Why doesn't it honor the priorities I set?

Comment: I think it's jersey bug. If I use the @Priority annotation to set the priority it works fine. but if I use register method to set priority. It ignores it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `javax.annotation.Priority` annotations instead of the 2nd parameter in `FeatureContext::register` and `ResourceConfig::register` calls, which overrides the annotation.

```
@Priority(1)
public class MyDynamicFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {
...
@Priority(2)
public class MyStaticFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {
...
featureContext.register(MyDynamicFilter.class);
...
register(MyDynamicFeature.class);
register(MyStaticFilter.class);
```

And if that leads to the same problem, update your dependencies.