# Jersey2 ContainerRequestFilter not executing before autentication

Tags: security, jersey-2.0

I am trying to get security working with my jersey2 web app.

I register RolesAllowedDynamicFeature and my Request filter with AUTHENTICATION priority in my ResourceConfig

```
packages("example.jersey");
register(MyRequestFilter.class, Priorities.AUTHENTICATION);
register(RolesAllowedDynamicFeature.class);
```

I added @RolesAllowed to the method

```
@RolesAllowed("quinn")
@GET
@Path("/")
public Response getIt(@Context UriInfo uriInfo) {
    return Response.ok().entity(service.get()).build();
}
```

In my request filter I set my security context

```
SecurityContext securityContext = containerRequestContext.getSecurityContext();
containerRequestContext.setSecurityContext(new MySecurityContext("gary", securityContext));
```

When I call the method from postman I get a 403 - Forbidden

I added logging to my request filter to see when it is called. It is NOT called.

If I remove the @RolesAllowed from the web method it does call the request filter.

It seems the Priorities.AUTHENTICATION is not making a difference.

Is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: What happens if you add `@Priority(Priorities.AUTHENTICATION)` on top of the filter, and comment out the `register(MyFilter...)`. I'm thinking maybe the filter is being registered some other way, maybe by package scan, and the explicit register doesn't take effect. I couldn't reproduce the problem, but I'm thinking if it _is_ getting registered some other scanning way, the `@Priority` annotation should work

Answer (score 1):

Your filter is implemented as a post-matching filter. It means that the filters would be applied only after a suitable resource method has been selected to process the actual request i.e. after request matching happens. Request matching is the process of finding a resource method that should be executed based on the request path and other request parameters.

@RolesAllowed blocks the selection of the particular resource method giving you the 'not executing' behavior you mentioned.

You have two options... using [@PreMatching as explained here](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/filters-and-interceptors.html).

Or, use [custom annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31974857/jersey-2-containerrequestfilter-get-method-annotation/37427428#37427428) as explained on a similar question.

Comment: RolesAllowedRequestFilter is also a post-matching filter. How exactly does RolesAllowedRequestFilter 'block' the selection of the particular resource method ?